# Instantiate an image to appear at several different points on the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have an image called Empty.png, it is a small-ish square tile, how could I instantiate the image to appear at several different points on the screen?

Thank you for any help in advance :)

Comment: Please give some more details .Try to put some code .

Answer (score 1):

You can can place `UIImageView`'s wherever you want the image to appear.And then set the image property of each image view as this image. (`UIImage` object).

If you are using interface builder then you just have to type in the name of the file in the attributes inspector of the `imageview` in the interface builder.

Or you could do this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageName:@"Empty.png"];
imageView.image = img; //Assuming this is your utlet to the image view.
```

Answer (score 0):

this will get you one image into some view

```
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(x,y);
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Empty.png"];
img.frame = CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, img.image.size.width, img.image.size.height);
[someUIView addSubview:img];
```

if you make an array for the positions (x,y) of all the images, then you can just run it in a for loop and it will place the images into the view at the positions you want

note: CGPoints cant be stored in an NSArray since its not an NSObject type, either use a C/C++ array or use something else that can fit into a NSArray

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to use it.

If you just draw it with core graphics, let's say in `drawInRect:` or so, then you simply draw it several times.

If you want to display it within one or a number of image views, then instanciate your UIImageViews and assign the same object to all of them. Or let the Interface Builder do the instanciation for you. But you cannot add a single UIView object several times to one or a number of subview-hierarchies. If you add a UIView as subview to a view then it will disappear from the position where it was before. 
10 UIImageView may use the same UIView but you need 10 UIImageViews to display all of them.

The same applies to UIButtons and every UI-thing that has an image or background image.